# How to install my video card to the VirtualBox (Ubuntu host, Windows guest)?

Tags: video, windows, virtualbox, 3d

I'm using the Sun VirtualBox with Guest Additions, and I'm not able to run some applications that need a 3D video card support.

The video card installed in the virtual box is "VirtualBox Graphics Adapter".

I'm using Windows XP guest and Ubuntu host.

My video card support 3D apps very well, is there a way to make it work in the VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best knowledge, you cannot install your host's adapter in the guest OS, although you can enable 3D acceleration in VirtualBox.

You can find a detailed documentation in the [corresponding section of the official VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d).

Comment: Ok, it's still experimental, so maybe I better use dual boot, as it's for work..

Comment: I suggest you to try it before voting down the idea. According to my tests it's working pretty well. Maybe the only downside of this, is what the manuals says: "Enabling 3D acceleration may expose security holes to malicious software running in the guest.".

Comment: Some 3D software does run fairly well in VirtualBox - but nowhere close to the performance you get in a dual-boot setting.